# Jackson-JQ: Running jq commands from java

Tags: java, jackson, jq

I am trying to use jackson-jq to do delete some nodes on all JSON files in a directory and then merge them into a single JSON file.

I have been able to get this to work in JQ like below

```
//Cleanup
FILES=*.json
  for f in $FILES; do
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    cat $f | jq 'del(.precondition, .testFailureClassname, .testFailureMessage) >tempfile && mv tempfile $f
  done

//Merge
jq -s '.' *.json >"$basedir"/target/results.json
```

But I am not sure how to achieve this using jackson-jq. Any pointers?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [jackson-jq](https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq) readme presumably you download the jar

```
$ curl -LO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/thisptr/jackson-jq-cli/1.0.0-preview.20191208/jackson-jq-cli-1.0.0-preview.20191208.jar
```

verify it works

```
$ java -jar jackson-jq-cli-1.0.0-preview.20191208.jar --help
usage: jackson-jq [OPTIONS...] QUERY
 -c,--compact      compact instead of pretty-printed output
 -h,--help         print this message
    --jq <arg>     specify jq version
 -n,--null-input   use `null` as the single input value
 -r,--raw          output raw strings, not JSON texts
```

and then use `java -jar jackson-jq-cli-1.0.0-preview.20191208.jar`
where you would have used `jq`, e.g.

```
$ echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | java -jar jackson-jq-cli-1.0.0-preview.20191208.jar '.foo'
"bar"
```